# Flask Server returns response after significant delay when called with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, flask, server

I have 2 servers running on localhost with different ports. 
One is a simple flask server in python and the code is added below:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify("Hello, World!")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,threaded=True)
```

When I send a GET request from Postman or any existing Client it works like a charm. But when I use Apache to  host some existing JavaScript AJAX code to do the same , there is significant delay in response. Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
    function loadDoc() {

      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
          alert(this.responseText)
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }
    </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="demo">
  <h1>Welcome to our application</h1>
  <br>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Print Hello World!</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes I don't even receive a response. Any quick suggestions would be helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer in the documentation of WSGI applications which says:

On operating systems that support ipv6 and have it configured such as modern Linux systems, OS X 10.4 or higher as well as Windows Vista some browsers can be painfully slow if accessing your local server. The reason for this is that sometimes “localhost” is configured to be available on both ipv4 and ipv6 sockets and some browsers will try to access ipv6 first and then ipv4. Try removing

```
::1     localhost
```

from the hosts file on your system.